# Add a line before another matched line in vim

Tags: vb.net, vim

I have a bunch of properties that I need to put attributes on.

I'd like to:
For each line that starts with "`Public Property...`", insert the line `<DataMember()> _` immediately above it.

Any idea how I'd do this in vi/vim?

Comment: You're doing VB in vim?  You're nuts dude

Comment: @DouglasBarbin - 1. Not my choice of language here, doing legacy cleanup work.  2.  It's actually vsvim in VS2010.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin vim is a text editor, why cannot "doing VB" in vim? I wrote a big windows batch script in vim last week. btw, the syntax of win-batch is.... strange.

Comment: I thought that he was using regular old vi/vim, maybe with Mono or something.  I know that he can use it, my point was that it's a much less user-friendly IDE than Visual Studio.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin vim is NOT an IDE at all. :D it is editor.

Comment: @Kent Take a look at:  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Vim_like_an_IDE ,
http://haridas.in/vim-as-your-ide.html , 
etc...

Comment: @Kent - If I need to change the tags to something else, let me know.  I wasn't sure what to pick.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin I know people can use vim **like** an IDE with plugins, customized functions, but it is not an IDE. there is vim-plugin, which can play mp3 audio files in vim (with python support). Can we say vim is a mp3 player?

Comment: @J.Polfer what do you want to change into? I mean the tag.

Comment: @J.Polfer oh, sorry, you mean the tag of the question.... I thought you want to change the `<DataMember()>` "tag"... :D :D

Answer (score 3):

how about using the `:g` command:

```
:g/^Public Property/norm! O<DataMember()>
```

if you like you can use `:s` too:

```
:%s/^Public Pr.../<Data...>\r&
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
:%s/\(^Public Property.\+$\)/<DataMember()>\r\1/
```